# What does Str1[j] = (portData >> j) & 0x1; mean in C#

Tags: c#

What does this particular code mean?

```
byte portData;

 for (var i = 1; i < InstantDiCtrl.Features.PortCount; ++i)
 {
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    {
        Str1[j] = (portData >> j) & 0x1;
    }
 }
```

I am confused on this part

```
Str1[j] = (portData >> j) & 0x1;
```

Comment: `Str1` - is an array; `>>` is a bitwise shift operator; `&` is a logical AND. What exactly is confusing you? Have you tried to move with a debugger through this code and understand what is it doing?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/141525/1300049

Comment: The code just shifts bits out and compares them with one, in essence turning a byte into a bit array (binary)